emacs markdown mode selecting org-mode header level?
in markdown mode, emacs allows SHIFT-TAB to cycle between content view (1 level), outline view (all levels), and document view (all text).  I would like to have one of them go down only two levels or add another view that just has two levels.  Is there a customization variable I could stick into .emacs that would do this?

I don't see a way to add an additional cycling level by way of user customization.
A separate command that should show the 2-level view is C-2 M-x outline-hide-sublevels. But, it isn't convenient breaking the cycle.
One possibility is writing a custom version of markdown-shifttab, which doesn't require too much copy pasta.
(defun my-markdown-shifttab ()
  "Do `markdown-shifttab' with added 2-level view."
  (interactive)
  (cond ((markdown-table-at-point-p)
         (call-interactively #'markdown-table-backward-cell))
        (t (cond ((and (eq last-command this-command)
                       (eq markdown-cycle-global-status 3))
                  ;; Add extra view between "CONTENTS" and "SHOW ALL"
                  (setq this-command 'my-markdown-shifttab--extra)
                  (outline-hide-sublevels 2)
                  (markdown-outline-fix-visibility))
                 (t (when (eq last-command 'my-markdown-shifttab--extra)
                      ;; Enter back into default cycling
                      (setq last-command 'my-markdown-shifttab))
                    (markdown-cycle t))))))

